# Where to find files like pictures and music from Mac hard drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, photos, startup, music, recovery

So my father has a Mac that doesn't boot so I'm copying files from the hard drive to a USB. I am not a Mac user and am having difficulties finding where all the files like pictures and music would be stored. I would appreciate if people explained where I can find his desktop, music, and such. I am accessing the Terminal from the recovery section.

Answer (score 6):

If the defaults are in play, then the path to the `Users` folder of the `Macintosh HD` when booted from the `Recovery HD` is:

```
/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users
```

- <sup>**Update Note:** At the time this was originally posted it was accurate as stated, however, since **macOS Catalina** the actual physical location is `'/Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Users'`. That said, either *path* can be used to retrieve *user files* from.</sup>

Within that, the `Users` directory at the above path, there will be `Shared` directory and at least one other, which would be your fathers.

It is within that directory you'll find:

```
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Movies
Music
Pictures

Etc.
```

If you are doing this from macOS Recovery, I would probably opt to make a Disk Image of the target Users folder using Disk Utility > File > New > Disk Image from Folder.

Then at least you could do it using a GUI and it would retain all the meta-data too.

Note however, if you have removed the HDD/SSD and have it in an external enclosure connected to another computer, then the path to the `Users` folder is just `/Users`, meaning in the *root* of the volume.